# On what bases the size and range of any datatype is decided?

Tags: c#, java, c++, c

I what to know that what is the base on which the size of any datatype is decided. For eg. size of intger datatype in java is 4 bytes. So why its exactly 4 and not anything else. More over maximum number that can be stored with int type is 2,147,483,648. When this number come from? I mean what is the formula to get this number for anyother data type?

But why it is exactly 4? I still not clear. Some says that to represent any number in the range of perticular datatype. But there are other dataypes also which provide larger range. Still so much confused...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In assembler size in bits of the types is defined by the architecture that has to work with the numbers. Most current architectures group bits in 8-bit bytes, and double the size of the number when going to the next type: 8, 16, 32, 64, 128... but not all architectures support all the types, and some old architectures had *weird* types (14 bit integers, for example).

When you use a programming language, the language abstracts the lower levels, and the types in the language are defined to abstract the lower level types. Depending on the language the types might differ: `char`, `short int`, `int` some proposed [`short`, `tall`, `grande`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/15/double-half-caf-with-a-twist-of-lemon.aspx). In some cases it will be exactly defined (in Java or C# an `int` is exactly 32bits, and a `long` is 64bits), while in others like C/C++ only the relationships among the types are defined (`long` is not smaller than `int` which in turn is not smaller than `short`, then `char`...)

The maximum number that a given unsigned type can hold can be calculated as `2^N-1`, so for a 32 bit unsigned int, the maximum value is `4294967295`. The reason for the `-1` part is that there are `2^N` distinct numbers, one of which is `0`, so only `2^N-1` are left for non-zero values.

When it comes to signed integer types, again the architecture has much to say. Most current architectures use [two's-complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). In those platforms the highest signed value for an `N` bit signed integer will be `2^(N-1)-1` and the most negative number will be `-2^(N-1)`. Some older architectures reserved one bit for the sign and then stored the actual number, in which case the negative range would be reduced by one (this approach allows for two zero values: `0` and `-0`).

As to your question, you will have to pick the language first. Then, in the case of C or C++, you will have to pick your platform, and even the compiler. While in most cases the types are directly related (`int` is 32 bits in *most* 32 and 64bit architectures in C++), that is not guaranteed, and some types might differ (`long` might represent a 32 or 64bit integer type). As of the actual size of a type in C++ besides `char` that is guaranteed to have `CHAR_BITS` bits, you can use `sizeof(type)*CHAR_BITS` to get the size in bits.

Answer (score 3):

Because 4 bytes is 4*8 = 32 bits.
2^32 = 4294967296
For unsigned int that is the max number, for signed int it's 2^32/2, which is your number.
The number of bytes on which a datatype is represented is decided by the architecture. For C++, only sizeof(char) is guaranteed to be 1.

Comment: The max is actually `2^(N-1)-1` for a signed integer type of `N` bits in two's-complement notation. So for 32bits it is `2^31-1` or `2147483647` (the number in the question is also wrong)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where got your number from, this is wrong. Maximum numbers for such types are always odd and not even.

For `unsigned` types C prescribes that it always uses a representation with bits, say x bits. The maximum is then always 2 to the power of x minus 1, thus an odd number.

For `signed` types the rules are similar for the maximum (thus positive) value. For the minimum value things are a bit more complicated, but usually this uses the so-called two's complement representation for negative numbers and the minimum value is then usually the (negative of the maximum value) minus one, so an even number.

Answer (score 2):

4 bytes = 4*8 bits = 32 bits. Now 2^32 = 4294967296. Divide by 2, you get 2147483648. So int spans from -2147483648 to +2147483648.

Comment: Actually 2^32 = 4294967296. You forgot about negative values.

Comment: Yep, 24h sleepless hours did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is all determined by hardware. 32-bit platforms were in the vogue when these languages were designed. This meant that it was most efficient to operate with 32-bit numbers and that pointers were 32-bit. The most common platforms had 8-bit bytes, so 32 bits are 4 bytes. The most common signed integer representation was [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%27s_complement), so the largest representable number is 2<sup>31</sup>-1 or 2,147,483,648 and the smallest is -2<sup>31</sup> or  2,147,483,647. An unsigned integer has the range from 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1 or 4,294,967,295.

C++ does not actually require integers to have these sizes. It is meant for writing efficient code on a wider range of platforms, so it says:

> There are four signed integer types: "signed char", "short int", "int", and "long int." In this list, each type provides at least as much storage as those preceding it in the list. Plain intss have the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment; the other signed integer types are provided to meet special needs.

Answer (score 0):

In a slight variant of Vladimir:

Int is a signed data type, so as Vladimir says:

```
4 bytes = 4*8 bits = 32 bits.
```

Actually though, `2^32 = 4,294,967,296`.

Because this is signed, you half this value, so max = `4,294,967,296 / 2 = 2,147,483,648`

Answer (score 0):

To begin, computer only understand [binary digit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system) (0 and 1).
8 binary digits (bits) group together will form the least-addressable memory unit (byte).

Since byte can only represent 256 different states and it is far less than what we require. Other [units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_information) are defined by using multiple bytes to represent single value, such as `int` to represent integer.

The way each unit is interpreted can be found in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive data types tend to be based on those provided by the hardware architecture for efficiency reasons. Even platform independent languages such as Java and C# have been designed with common 32 bit processors in mind. As others have explained the minimum and maximum values of integral types depend on the lowest and highest numbers that can be represented in the number of bits that are available in each type, reserving one bit to represent the sign for signed types.